# Receiving error when creating FirebaseAuth instance create & sign in with email and password

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I receive an error in Android Studio when creating a user sign in method using FirebaseAuth and FirebaseUser. Mainly telling me to either cast or change FirebaseUser to AuthResult both of which leads to a failure to create a firebase user resulting in No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth.

I have tried the responses from Android Studio without luck. The best fix is to revert to an earlier FirebaseAuth version. I'm currently using version: firebase_auth: ^0.14.0.

`FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);`

I receive `error: A value of type 'AuthResult' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.` when using the above code.

When I change `FirebaseUser` to `AuthResult` or cast it as `as FirebaseUser`, I receive `No implementation found for method createUserWithEmailAndPassword on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth.`and it doesn't create the user in the Firebase database.

How can I use the latest version of FirebaseAuth without running into this error?

Edit: I have tried the related questions/answers on the topic to no avail including using latest SDKcompile versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There was a breaking change in version 0.12.0. Check the Changelog here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-changelog-tab-

> Breaking Change. Sign-in methods now return AuthResult instead of
>   FirebaseUser. Retrieve the FirebaseUser using the user property of
>   AuthResult.

I haven't updated my package yet, but I imagine it would look something like this.

```
AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);

FirebaseUser user = result.user;
```

Comment: This is correct, thanks. I had to follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27090 to get it to work. Seems there are a few issues with Firebase, Futter and Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me -

```
AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);   FirebaseUser user = result.user;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me **(i'm using firebase_auth: ^0.14.0 firebase_database: ^3.0.5)** event it say it's unnecceessary cast,
u may also try this.

```
FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)) as FirebaseUser;
```

Comment: This is not the answer, as described in question. Answer by Eric is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Casting throws an error. 
 This worked for me:

AuthResult auth = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);

auth.user // FIREBASE USER